# python lists having chars and digits

Tags: python

if I have a list:

```
x=[1,'A',2,'B',3,'C',2,'A',1,'B']
```

here in the above list the digits and characters are related as A contains 1,B contains 2, C contains 3 and again A contains 2(total 3) ,B contains 1(total 3)

if I want to find what each character contains finally..how can I do it
I did this-
I found characters in the list x initially like `y=['A','B','C']` then I used a loop to iterate x and whenever I find A in x I added the previous value based on index and so on...but  its not working sometimes.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried? The code.

Comment: So the numbers are always in not-even positions?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean be "A contains 1"?

Comment: yes the numbers are in odd positions

Comment: @offeltoffel  something like dictionary key value pair but in the form of a list

Comment: I would like to help you but it seems impossible to understand what you are trying to do. The connection between char and digits remains unclear to me. It would be best if you showed us some piece of code

Comment: This not only lacks an attempt to solve, but the list is a syntax error. So probably this is asked without even starting an editor or doing anything on own thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming you want a dictionary as output:

```
data = [1,'A',2,'B',3,'C',2,'A',1,'B']

result = {}
for number, letter in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
    result.setdefault(letter, []).append(number)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'B': [2, 1], 'C': [3], 'A': [1, 2]}
```

If you want only the last *contained* number, you could use a dictionary comprehension (see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)):

```
data = [1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 2, 'A', 1, 'B']
result = {letter: number for number, letter in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'B': 1, 'C': 3, 'A': 2}
```

Or if you want the sum of all elements, you can use a combination of both answer above:

```
data = [1,'A',2,'B',3,'C',2,'A',1,'B']

result = {}
for number, letter in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
    result.setdefault(letter, []).append(number)

result = { letter : sum(numbers) for letter, numbers in result.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}
```

**Further**

1. Documentation on [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
2. Documentation on [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: except, instead of append, you can just directly assign a value instead to the key. `result[letter] = number` As the OP only wants the last value.

Comment: I think OP wanted `result[letter] = result.get(letter, 0) + number` instead

Comment: ty for the code ...can I know what does zip and setdefault do

Comment: @Ramesh updated the post with links to the documentation, basically zip, joins iterables so you can iterate over them in parallel. And setdefault, sets a default value for the dictionary

Comment: can we write `result = { letter : sum(numbers) for letter, numbers in result.items()}` as `for letter, numbers in result.items() :
 result  = {letter : sum(numbers)}` ?

Comment: No, it will be more like: `for letter, numbers in result.items(): 
    result[letter] = sum(numbers)`